# How to draw a non-continous series

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a discontinued (non-continous) series. This is the code for the series:

```
        Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(20000, 30);
        Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(1000000, 30);
        //no plotting wanted here
        Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(1500000, 40);
        Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(2500000, 40);
```

How do I stop it from plotting certain points, like the diagonal line shown in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visually break up a line chart by inserting an **invisible** `DataPoint`:

```
    Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(20000, 30);
    Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(1000000, 30);
    //no plotting wanted (from previous point to this one) here
    int index = Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(1500000, 40);
    Chart.Series["Limit"].Points[index].Color = Color.Transparent;
    Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(2500000, 40);
```

This makes **the line that leads to** the `DataPoint` **transparent**.

Comment: Thank you kind sir, that's what i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any way to set different lines parameters for the same Series, but you can create two different lines

```
Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(20000, 30);
Chart.Series["Limit"].Points.AddXY(1000000, 30);
Chart.Series["Limit"].BorderColor = Color.Red
//no plotting wanted here
Chart.Series["Limit2"].Points.AddXY(1500000, 40);
Chart.Series["Limit2"].Points.AddXY(2500000, 40);
Chart.Series["Limit2"].BorderColor = Color.Red
```